# Error Apt Install raspberrypi-kernel-headers

Tags: kernel

I have a Raspberry Pi I installed Ubuntu on using the Ubuntu Desktop Image. I am trying to get the RaspbeeII software installed and it requires raspberrypi-kernel-headers.

When I do apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers I am getting an error and I don't know how to resolve it.

> E: Unable to locate package raspberrypi-kernel-headers

How do I get this installed? This is what I get when I try a make:

> make
>
> checking deb package dependencies...
>
> i2c-tools
>
> build-essential
>
> raspberrypi-kernel-headers
>
> package raspberrypi-kernel-headers not installed, please install via: apt-get install 
> raspberrypi-kernel-headers
>
> make: *** [Makefile:26: check-packages] Error 1

Any help on getting this so I can get this software installed?

The software in question is:

https://phoscon.de/en/raspbee2/install

Comment: You cannot install the Raspberry Pi OS in your Raspberry Pi from inside Ubuntu. Create a new SD card with Pi OS, or overwrite the old one with Pi OS image.

Comment: The software link posted in the question above clearly says the supported OS is Raspberry Pi OS, previously known as Raspbian. The instructions are for that OS, not Ubuntu.

Comment: You've provided no actual OS/release details; Ubuntu has multiple products for the pi that use different package commands and you've not said what you're using. You should provide full details, ie. are you asking about Ubuntu Core 20?  Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS etc.  You'll need to *adjust* instructions if using a different OS to what it was tailored for as per prior comments.